# Transformar igraph.vs em dataframe

Tags: r

Após obter a lista de caminhos com origem num determinado vértice (p.e. A) através de `all_simple_paths`:

```
library(igraph)

ligacoes <- data.frame(origem = c("A","A", "B", "B", "D"), 
                       destino=c("B","D","C","D", "E"), 
                       valor=c(31.2, 100, 1, 85, 2))

grafo1 <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(ligacoes[1:2]))
E(grafo1)$valor <- ligacoes$valor

all_simple_paths(grafo1, V(grafo1)["A"])
```

necessitava registar a informação num dataframe, alguém pode ajudar?

Por exemplo, para avaliação de todos os caminhos existentes com origem no vértice A o objetivo final seria obter algo semelhante a:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode incluir um exemplo do formato que deseja para o data.frame final? `all_simple_paths` e outras funções do tipo retornam listas porque os caminhos possuem comprimento diferente.

Comment: Foi adicionado o detalhe indicado, obg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As funções `*path` do igraph retornam uma lista de conexões (*edges*). Alguns atributos podem ser extraídos dela, mas o mais importante, pode usar os índices para indexar o grafo ou o data.frame com os dados.

```
library(igraph)

ligacoes <- data.frame(
  origem = c("A","A", "B", "B", "D"),
  destino = c("B","D","C","D", "E"),
  valor= c(31.2, 100, 1, 85, 2),
  peso = c(1,1,2,1,2))

grafo1 <- graph_from_data_frame(ligacoes)

# Nós que servem apenas de destino:
finais <- as.character(with(ligacoes, destino[!destino %in% origem]))

# Todos os caminhos que saem de A e terminam nos nós finais:
caminhos <- all_simple_paths(grafo1, from = "A", to = finais, mode = "out")
```

Por exemplo, para ter os valores do atributo `valor` para as conexões do primeiro caminho:

```
names(caminhos[[1]])
#> [1] "A" "B" "D" "E"

E(grafo1)[caminhos[[1]]]$valor
#> [1]  31.2 100.0   1.0   2.0
```

Sendo uma lista, pode fazer operações para todos os caminhos usando a família `apply`:

```
dados <- data.frame(
  caminho = sapply(caminhos, function(x) paste(names(x), collapse = "-")),
  comprimento = sapply(caminhos, length),
  valor_total = sapply(caminhos, function(x) sum(ligacoes[x, "valor"])),
  valor_ponderado = sapply(caminhos, function(x) sum(ligacoes[x, "valor"]*ligacoes[x, "peso"]))
)

dados
#>   caminho comprimento valor_total valor_ponderado
#> 1 A-B-D-E           4       134.2           137.2
#> 2   A-B-C           3       216.2           216.2
#> 3   A-D-E           3        34.2            37.2
```

PS: Não entendi com base em que fez a conta do valor no exemplo que postou, então inventei uma conta de demonstração.

Comment: Com esta opção consigo obter os registos associados aos caminhos 3,4 e 6. Como poderei obter os restantes caminhos apurados (os caminhos associados aos ID 1, 2 e 5)? (caminhos com origem em A e cujo destino não é um vértice obtido em “finais”)

Comment: Confira a ajuda para `all_simple_paths`: o padrão é usar todos os vértices como destino. É só remover `to = finais`.